# Can only upload images to AWS S3 from Django 3.1 app from admin , not from from my CustomUser app

Tags: django, amazon-s3, image-upload

From localhost,I can upload an image for a user from Django admin but I can't from the User app. I have created a Custom User so that I can use email as the username (not sure if this is relevant).

I have also tried setting AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4' but this does not work either.

The image associated with the CustomUser is added using the Profile model which has a one-to-one association with the CustomUser model.

I am puzzled as to why it works from Django admin but not from the actual app itself.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I am a newbie to Django as well.

The following are snippets from the relevant files:

settings.py

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ap-southeast-2'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

forms.py:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
    from django import forms
    from .models import CustomUser, Profile


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)
        

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)


class ProfileChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image',]
```

models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.email} Profile'
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = CustomUserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileChangeForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated.')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = CustomUserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileChangeForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe how trivial the solution was. In my upload template I left the "i" out of `enctype="multipart/form-data`

Problem solved !!